# Should each machine in a high availability cluster have same time zone?

Tags: high-availability, timezone

I'm curious if people with experience think it makes sense to give all machines in a replication cluster the same time zone and time regardless of physical location to help ensure that dates are stored, and tasks are run all at the same time according to the shared time zone.

Could this be considered a best practice or something completely app-specific?

Comment: yes, use your local timezone of your business.

Comment: @ADM: No. Use UTC and see the link in my answer for an excellent example why this is a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to always use UTC as your only timezone to avoid any confusion, e.g. with [DST issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/604510/why-is-there-a-difference-with-unix-date-between-2-and-3-months). In a cluster, this or at least the *same* TZ on any host is essential, IMHO.